# Resource text being cropped when starts with number and used with @Html.Label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

I have the following code:

Resource File:

```
 SecondYieldEstimation  ===> "2. Ertragsschätzung"
```

View

```
 @Html.Label(ResContractProduction.SecondYieldEstimation, new {@class = "col-md-3 col-form-label"})
 <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for=""> @ResContractProduction.SecondYieldEstimation</label>
```

And the output is:

```
<label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for=""> Ertragsschätzung</label>
<label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for=""> 2. Ertragsschätzung</label>
```

Why is the `"2. "` being cropped from the text when I use the `@Html.Label()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because if you look at the overloads of  `@Html.Label` the `1st overload` says `string expression` means it thinks `"2. Ertragsschätzung"` is some property of model thats why it removes `2.` and take `Ertragsschätzung` and `2nd overload` is `string labelText` means the string you want to show so you have to do something like this

```
@Html.Label("",ResContractProduction.SecondYieldEstimation, new { @class = "col-md-3 col-form-label" })
```